# Variadic template not working with an initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I created a factory function template:

```
template <typename M, typename... Args>
std::shared_ptr<M> create(Args... args)
{
    return std::make_shared<M>(args...);
}
```

And a simple container:

```
struct Group {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    Group(std::initializer_list<int> il) : vec(il) {}
};
```

Then I try to create a Group

```
int main()
{
    auto gr = create<Group>({1, 2, 3});
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't compile,

```
error: no matching function for call to 'create'
    auto gr = create<Group>({1, 2, 3});
candidate function not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
std::shared_ptr<M> create(Args... args)
                   ^
```

but if I use a temporary variable:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::initializer_list<int> il = {1, 2, 3};
    auto gr = create<Group>(il);
    return 0;
}
```

it does. Why?

What is the recommended solution for such case?

Comment: I *think* the problem is that the compiler actually doesn't know what to do with `{ 1, 2, 3 }` when itis passed to `create()`: it would need to determine a suitable type but there is no guidance on what type that should be. If you used `std::initializer_list{ 1, 2, 3 }` or overloaded `create()` to take an `std::initailizer_list<T>` (with `T` being a template parameter) it should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A template parameter cannot be deduced from an initializer list (it's a non-deduced context), but can from an expression of type `std::initializer_list<something>`. The two are not the same.

> **[temp.deduct.call]/1** Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function template parameter type (call it `P`) with the type of the corresponding argument of the call (call it `A`) as described below. If removing references and cv-qualifiers from `P` gives `std::initializer_list<P'>` for some `P'` and the argument is an initializer list (8.5.4), then deduction is performed instead for each element of the initializer list, taking `P'` as a function template parameter type and the initializer element as its argument. Otherwise, an initializer list argument causes the parameter to be considered a non-deduced context (14.8.2.5). [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class T> void f(std::initializer_list<T>);
> f({1,2,3}); // T deduced to int
> f({1,"asdf"}); // error: T deduced to both int and const char*
>
> template<class T> void g(T);
> g({1,2,3}); // error: no argument deduced for T
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

Comment: What is the recommended solution for such case?

Comment: Well, none, really. `std::make_shared` [doesn't handle this case](http://rextester.com/OFMSA41863), either. The caller needs some kind of a workaround, like the one you've discovered. Why are you reinventing `std::make_shared` anyway, if you don't mind me asking? Why not just call it directly?

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

> A *braced-init-list* is not an expression and therefore has no type, e.g. `decltype({1,2})` is ill-formed. Having no type implies that template type deduction cannot deduce a type that matches a *braced-init-list*, so given the declaration `template<class T> void f(T);` the expression `f({1,2,3})` is ill-formed.

There is one exception though: `auto a = { 1, 2 };` results in `a` being a `std::initializer_list`. But this is only in `auto` type deducing, not for templates.

Comment: What is the recommended solution for such case?